# video playing from asset folder but not playing from server in android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

I am trying to play video in my app. It is playing video when file is stored in asset folder but not playing video when file is on server.

`I want to play video from server`

My source code is

```
 class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
    protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        String fileName = args[0];
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
        Log.i("sushi", "Background thread starting");

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            try {

                //InputStream in = am.open("pages/rice/test2.3gp");
                InputStream in = am.open("http://inveniya.net/jasmine/test2.mp4");
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                f.close();
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("sushi", e.getMessage());
            }

            if (VideoActivity.this.pd != null) {
                VideoActivity.this.pd.dismiss();
                VideoActivity.this.pd = null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Thank you advance for any advice

Comment: Did you remember to add the Network Connection in the Manifest file and is it throwing any errors in the Cat Log?

Comment: yes,i add network connection in manifest. below is <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: I found one cause in my app. I use `AssetManager am = getAssets();` here. It should change. But what should be in place of `AssetManager am = getAssets();`?

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE`

I solved the problem with `URL url = new URL("http://inveniya.net/jasmine/test2.mp4"); InputStream in = url.openStream();`

It is working properly and playing video from server.